# How to send message in response by jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using Post method in jquery

```
$.post("default.aspx", { 
    ajaxrequest: "yes",
    email: "example@demo.com" 
}).success(function (d) {
    alert('mail sent successfully.');
    $(".register_button_main").attr('disabled','disabled');
}).error(function (d) {
    alert(d.status); 
    $(".register_button_main").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

but if any exception occur in server side function then i want to send my message in response how can i do this. please suggest.

Comment: Show server side code, I think it should be `default.aspx/somemethod`

Comment: You need to use `try {} catch { response.write(ex.ToString()); }` on the server to capture and return "any exception".

Comment: i tried try {} catch { response.write(ex.ToString()); } , but when i put try{} catch{}  it doesnt come in error function it always go to .success(function (d) {
    alert('mail sent successfully.');
    $(".register_button_main").attr('disabled','disabled');

Comment: and my url is only "default.aspx"  i am using request.Param[""] in server side to execute server side method

Comment: Have you tried setting a custom error status code on the response? Then end the catch block with a `return null;` statement so the rest of the code is ignored?